# I want to display foreign keys in one table from other tables, but I get foreign key mismatch error

Tags: java, database, sqlite, netbeans

I'm very new to SQL and I want the **contracts_tb** (query details below) is to display and link the foreign id keys referred from:

```
med_idref (referred from med_id (INTEGER), PRIMARY KEY o mediaadv_tb),
mediatitle_ref (title (TEXT), mediaadv_tb),
       mediatype_red (mtype (TEXT), mediaadv_tb),
cus_idref (cus_id (INTEGER),PRIMARY KEY of customer_tb), 
cus_companyref (referred from company (TEXT), in customer_tb)
```

All to be linked and displayed to **contracts_tb**.  When I add/replace values from **mediaadv_tb** and **customer_tb**, I get this problem:

> foreignkey mismatch

Also, do I have to make or assign a parent table?

Query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer_tb;    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer_tb (
    cus_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    company TEXT, 
    firstname TEXT, 
    middlename TEXT, 
    lastname TEXT, 
    gender TEXT, 
    dob TEXT, 
    dateregistered TEXT, 
    contactno  TEXT, 
    emailaddress TEXT, 
    description TEXT, 
    refpic INTEGER,
    cuspic BLOB
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mediaadv_tb;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mediaadv_tb (
    med_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    mtype TEXT,
    duration TEXT,
    title TEXT, 
    dateadded TEXT,
    desription TEXT,
    previewimg BLOB, 
    filepath TEXT
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contracts_tb;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contracts_tb (
    contract_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    customer_idref INTEGER REFERENCES customer_tb (cus_id),
    media_idref INTEGER REFERENCES mediaadv_tb (med_id),
    media_typeref TEXT REFERENCES mediaadv_tb(mtype),
    media_titleref TEXT REFERENCES mediaadv_tb (title), 
    status TEXT, 
    priority TEXT, 
    dateadded TEXT, 
    dateexpiration TEXT, 
    amountpaid REAL, 
    arearofcoverage TEXT 

);
```

---

Error :-

[image]

**contracts_tb**

[image]

**mediaadv_tb**

[image]

Comment: It's very difficult to read your question, let alone understand it. Please read [ask] and learn how to use [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), or at least use the built-in formatter.

Comment: MikeT you've always been my guardian angel man thanks a lot!

Comment: Try removing the REFERENCES mediaadv_tb(column) from  **media_typeref**  and **media_titleref** i.e. so those two columns aren't foreign keys. To be foreign keys you'd have to create UNIQUE indexes and that's what the message is telling you. [SQLite Foreign Key Support - 3. Required and Suggested Database Indexes](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Comment: Ohhhh I thought you could make the program automatically refer the ids to the existing referred ones from other tables lol. Never thought about that tganks

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your issue is because the foreign keys defined that reference the **media_typeref** and the **media_titleref** columns are invalid as they do not have, or are part of a, UNIQUE indexes (no indexes). [SQLite Foreign Key Support - 3. Required and Suggested Database Indexes](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

The referenced **id** columns, as they are INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, are implicitly UNIQUE indexes.

Furthermore the two columns (typeref and titleref) themself aren't even needed as the media_idref column would be used to identify the reference and thus would hold the respective values. Copying those values into the contracts table would be contrary to normalisation and may even create major headaches (e.g. if a value changed you'd have to find all other uses and also change them).

As such I'd suggest that the **contracts_tb** be created using :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contracts_tb;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contracts_tb (
    contract_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    customer_idref INTEGER REFERENCES customer_tb (cus_id),
    media_idref INTEGER REFERENCES mediaadv_tb (med_id),
    status TEXT, 
    priority TEXT, 
    dateadded TEXT, 
    dateexpiration TEXT, 
    amountpaid REAL, 
    arearofcoverage TEXT 
);
```

#### Re comment :-

> What i'm making is a Java NetBeans SQLite database program, where by
>   using the Contracts frame, whevenr one makes a new contract, there
>   will be a combobox that restricts the user to only put the existing
>   ids or names that is referred in the contracts_tb then provides the
>   choices. Is it possible sir?

Yes.

More specifically:-

Assume that you have **customers** Fred, Bert and Harry (id's 1,2 and 3 respectively). And that you have **mediaadv**'s M1, M2 and M3 (id's 10,11 and 12 (not 1,2 and 3 to help distinguish between mediaadv and customers)).

Additionally I'll assume the suggested contracts_tb table as opposed to the original in the question (i.e. 2 columns dropped as suggested)

The when inserting a new contract, you present a list (combobox) of the customers e.g.

Fred

Bert

Harry

(this list could be generated from a query such as:-

- `SELECT cus_id,firstname FROM customer_tb;` i.e. all existing customers)
- If you wanted Fred James Bloggs then you could use :-

  - `SELECT cus_id,firstname||' '||middlename||'lastname' AS fullname FROM customer_tb;`.

Likewise a list of the existing mediaadv could be generated from a query such as:-

- `SELECT med_id, description FROM mediaadv_tb;` e.g.

so the combobox would have:-

M1

M2

M3

Now if the contract were for Bert (id **2**) and M1 (id **10**) then you build SQL something like :-

`INSERT INTO contracts_tb VALUES(null,2,10,'the_status','the_priority','yyyy-mm-dd','yyyy-mm-dd',500,'the_coverage');`

- 1st value is null  i.e. no value, so as contract_id is an alias of the rowid it will be generated.
- 2 is the id of the customer (hence why cus_id was in the query as you need the id as it's the value you are going to store)
- 10 is the id of the mediaadv (again hence why med_id was in the query as you need the id as it's the value you are going to store).
- the other values are what they should be.
- Note the above use of INSERT requires that all columns be given. You can skip columns by specifying a list of the columns e.g. `INSERT INTO contracts_tb (customer_idref,media_idref) VALUES(2,10);`

As a customer with an cus_id of 2 (Bert) exists then the constraint that customer_idref is an existing id in the customer_tb is good/met and there is no conflict.

Likewise as there is a row in mediaadv_tb that has an med_id of 10 this constraint is good/met and there is no conflict.

However say the SQL were :-

`INSERT INTO contracts_tb VALUES(null,2,100,'the_status','the_priority','yyyy-mm-dd','yyyy-mm-dd',500,'the_coverage');`

Then as there is no med_id of 100 the constraint saying that media_idref must reference a value of 100 (in this instance) in the mediaadv_tb, column med_id, then the constraint will not be met and the insert will fail.

So again Yes, I believe  that what you want is feasible.

***Note a foreign key is only a constraint it doesn't bind/associate columns or join tables.***

Comment: Okay trying this now, never knew I have to set Text unique, sorry very new. Wait for my reply in a minute. I did something similar to that but whenever I make a new contract, I get foreign key problems. What i'm making is a Java NetBeans SQLite database program, where by using the Contracts frame, whevenr one makes a new contract, there will be a combobox that restricts the user to only put the existing ids or names that is referred in the contracts_tb then provides the choices. Is it possible sir?

Comment: It's like before you make a contract, you have to make sure that there is both a registered Customer and Advertisement input before the user proceed...